# i received this error 'Unpermitted parameter: image' in nested parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

this is my **profiles_controller.rb**

```
 def create

 @profile = current_user.build_profile(profile_params)

  if @profile.save
  else
    render :new 
  end
 end
 end
```

**profile.rb** has a nested attributes from **image.rb**

```
  params.require(:profile).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :phone_no, image_attributes: [:id,:image,:imageable_id,:imageable_type])
```

This is **profile.rb**

```
 class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 has_one :image , :as => :imageable
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :image
 end
```

this is **image.rb**

```
  class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
   end
```

this is **_form.html.erb** from **profile.rb** model

```
   <%= f.fields_for :image do |ff| %>
   <%= f.label :image %>
   <%= f.file_field :image %>
   <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= f.fields_for :image do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.label :image %> 
  <%= ff.file_field :image %>
<% end %>
```